# issue with codes execution order in javascript

Tags: javascript

test.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<body onload="init()">
```

test.js:

```
var req;
var isIE;
var completeField;
var completeTable;
var autoRow;
function init() {
    completeField = document.getElementById("complete-field");
    completeTable = document.createElement("table");
    console.log(completeTable);
    completeTable.setAttribute("class", "popupBox");
    completeTable.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
}
```

In console, it shows:

```
<table class="popupBox" style="display: none"></table>
```

Question:

`completeTable.setAttribute` runs after `console.log(completeTable);`, how come, it still shows the table attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `console.log` takes the state of the actual object when you look into the logged object... Try `alert(completeTable.getAttribute("style"))` instead and you will see there is no style yet.

Comment: logging primitive values will always print the value at the time of logging.